# AVPlayer plays video at double speed when view was not visible for a short amount of time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITabBarController. One tab has the VideoView with AVPlayer inside.

If I switch to another tab, like the "About" or "Settings" tab, the audio keeps playing, which is as intended.

But if I switch back to the Video tab, the video image continues at exactly the point, where I switched away, but with double speed until it caught up with the audio.

How can I prevent that and skip right to where the audio is, when coming back?

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found for now is:

```
[mPlayer seekToTime: mPlayer.currentTime]
```

This leads to a very small hickup. So I only do this if the video was not visible for over 3 seconds. As multiple of my tabs have a video player that the player gets tossed around to. That way I only do disturb the playback when really neccessary